# got 'fatal: branch 'master' does not exist' in git

Tags: git, git-branch

using `git` for a while, it's very powerful and beautiful..

but also got some confused about  it:

it should under branch master after I init a git repo, isn't it?

but `git branch -a`, i got nothing man.
and I got `fatal: branch 'master' does not exist` when I try to set upstream for my branch.

```
users@debian MINGW64 ~/Desktop/taste
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/users/Desktop/taste/.git/

users@debian MINGW64 ~/Desktop/taste (master)
$ git remote add origin git@gitee.com:greedev/Test.git

users@debian MINGW64 ~/Desktop/taste (master)
$ git branch -u origin/master
fatal: branch 'master' does not exist

users@debian MINGW64 ~/Desktop/taste (master)
$ git branch -a

users@debian MINGW64 ~/Desktop/taste (master)
$ git fetch
The authenticity of host 'gitee.com (120.55.226.24)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:FQGC9Kn/eye1W8icdBgrQp+KkGYoFgbVr17bmjey0Wc.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'gitee.com,120.55.226.24' (ECDSA) to the list of know                n hosts.
remote: Counting objects: 7, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 7 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (7/7), done.
From gitee.com:greedev/Test
* [new branch]      master     -> origin/master

users@debian MINGW64 ~/Desktop/taste (master)
$ git branch -a
  remotes/origin/master

users@debian MINGW64 ~/Desktop/taste (master)
$ git branch -u origin/master
fatal: branch 'master' does not exist
```

[image]

Answer (score 95, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You can `git checkout master` at this point.

#### Longer description (but still not that long)

You are doing this the hard way.

In the future, instead of:

```
mkdir repo
cd repo
git init
git remote add origin <url>
git fetch origin
git checkout master
```

you can simply run:

```
git clone <url> repo
```

since the six commands above are pretty much what `git clone` does.

After the first three steps—creating a new, totally-empty repository—you have a repository that is in a peculiar state: it has no commits, so it has no branches.  At the same time, it *does* have a *current branch*, which is `master`.

In other words, the current branch is a branch that *does not exist*.

This state is unusual, but normal.  If you run `git checkout --orphan newbranch`, you put your Git repository into that same state:<sup>1</sup> on a branch that does not exist.  The branch gets created once there is a commit hash to store under the branch name.

Whenever you run `git checkout <name>` and there is no branch named `<name>`, Git checks to see if there is *exactly one* remote-tracking branch such as `origin/<name>`.  If so, Git creates a *new* branch named `<name>` that points to the same commit as `origin/<name>` and that has `origin/<name>` as its upstream.

Since this last step—`git checkout master` when `master` does not actually exist yet—is the final step of `git clone`, `git clone` will also create a new branch `master` that tracks the remote-tracking branch `origin/master`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that you retain the current index / staging-area content.  This is true for the new empty repository as well, but since it's a new empty repository, the index / staging-area is also empty, and "retaining the empty set" does not feel much like retainment.

Comment: thx. you are legend. So, in practice,  `git clone` is doing what the `6_step` does. right? Gotcha.

Comment: It's doing all six of those steps (though it can skip the `mkdir` and use an existing empty directory if you tell it to do that). There are additional `git clone` arguments to modify some of the steps as desired, and the `git checkout` at the end is not always for `master`, but that's the usual pattern.

Answer (score 19):

After you run `git init`, the `master` you see is not completely created. It doesn't exist as it hasn't pointed to any commit yet. I once read that it was designed. But I think it's a puzzling bug. If you run `git branch`, it returns nothing.

After you run `git fetch`, a following `git checkout master` does the job. It is equivalent to:

```
git branch master origin/master
git checkout master
git branch -u origin/master
```

Comment: Basically this is right, but how you see it as a "bug" when, as you note, it is the documented behavior, I don't understand.  Of course since OP is working with a remote and fetching the whole thing anyway, the entire issue of an empty repo, as well as several unneeded steps, can be skipped by just using `git clone`

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger because it is unnecessarily confusing as obviously OP was confused by `master`. Maybe a badly designed feature if not a bug. `git clone` is not a generic solution. There are cases where we need to add a new remote in an existing repository, fetch from the remote and then checkout a new branch with its upstream.

Comment: thx a lot man, actually what i wanna know is `After you run git init, the master you see is not completely created. It doesn't exist as it hasn't pointed to any commit yet.`  U really gave me a big hand.O(∩_∩)O..

Comment: @ElpieKay - The fact that you don't know why it is the way it is does not make it "unnecessary". Your dislike for a design does not make it a bug.  The fact that a design sometimes confuses users dose not make it a bug.  As for `clone`, I was pretty clear about when it's applicable and certainly never said it was universal; however, if you're adding a remote to an existing repo, then it's not a brand new repo with no branch and so has nothing to do with this qusetion. Perhaps you should stop being unnecessarily argumentative.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger upvoted and thanks for you comment. As I've observed you are a good contributor in Stackoverflow. But, are you now teaching me how I must feel about a tool that I've been using every day? I gave a solution based on OP's steps and I never judged that `git-clone` was a bad solution. Stop being bossy please.

Comment: @ElpieKay - I defy you to point to where I told you how to feel.  My participation in this discussion is over.  (I will save you some time, though.  Disputing that it's a bug has nothing to do with "how you feel".)

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Very well. It shouldn't have been started.